# getInitialState() replacing existing state. How to pass existing state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making some buttons that will show a certain class depending on the status from the database.

I've passed my API results through an emitter and into my state using the below:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tickets: [],
      user: []
    };
    this.onGetAllTickets = this.onGetAllTickets.bind(this);
    this.onGetCurrentUser = this.onGetCurrentUser.bind(this);
  }
```

However, I'm having to set a new state in my button using the `getInitialState()` option. My button looks like this:

```
const AssignButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      isPressed: false,
      completeStatus: "Assign"
    };
  },
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isPressed: true,
      completeStatus: "Assigned",
    });
  },
  render () {
    var assignClass =  'ui orange right floated button assign';

    //THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO CHECK TICKET STATUS 
    if(this.state.tickets.status === 2) assignClass = 'ui green right floated button done disabled';
    else if(this.state.isPressed) assignClass += ' disabled';
    return <button className={assignClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.completeStatus}</button>;
  }
});
```

However, passing the `this.state.tickets.status` results in the following:

`TicketeesBoard.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined(…)`

I'm assuming this is because my state is overwritten by the `getInitialState()` method.

The `this.state.tickets.status` etc. works outside of this `AssignButton` component.

How do I pass my tickets from the original state into the `getInitialState()` method?

Comment: The first section of code (where you declare a state), does it 'live' in the parent? If so, it won't work.

Comment: @alexunder It all sits under `export default class TicketeesBoard extends React.Component` this component (this is the parent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the state of a different component. Your'e addressing `this.state.tickets.status` where ticket state is not declared in AssignButton

You've got two components. TicketBoard & AssignButton. 
Your setting the tickets state in TicketBoard and you're trying to access it in AssignButton

Try passing down the tickets state to the assignButton via props and the change your conditions from `this.state.tickets.status` to `this.props.tickets.status`.
In addition, make sure that you won't have problems with .status being called on an empty array...

Comment: But can I delare the `ticket.status` in the `getInitialState()`? I've tried `ticket: this.state.ticket` and several other tries, but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: Just to verify, `TicketeesBoard` is the parent component. Which is why I'm a little confused!

Comment: Mate, go over the docs again. 
State is per component. 
You set a state on the parent and try to access it in the child - doesn't work like that. 
If you want the child to be aware of the Parent's state, pass the data to the child using props.

Comment: If you want, put your code on jsfiddle and I'll help you with the proper adjustments over there.

Comment: Just trying it through `componentsWillMount` as I have an emitter setup from the API. Also, trying `props` to pass it through, but I'm not entirely sure how I pass the props to the 'child' component. The documentation does imply there's a kind of parent/child relationship using props. Thank you for the help by the way,.

Comment: Just adding on;  You're over-complicating this by a large margin.  You don't need to use **any** lifecycle hooks to accomplish your goal (no `getInitialState`, no `componentsWillMount`, or anything of that sort).  You just need to use props, which are a fundamental part of React.

Comment: @Dandy mate, I don't want to sound rude, I'm telling this from a good place - your last comment suggest that you miss the fundamentals of react. 
If you're not sure how to pass props to the child component, go back to the docs and go through them start to finish. 
If after you do so, you will have any additional questions, we're here to help :)

Comment: @alexunder I haven't needed to use props since starting this project. Hence, not real understanding of the benefits of using props. Went back, looked, used, understood. Cheers for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dandy Awesome! Glad I could help!